Master-Slave register with dynamic CMOS logic
I just cannot understand the operation of this circuit:
(there is an error in the transmission gate, the yellow "0" ... but whatever)

If the input (light blue) is 0 and the gate is closed (a short circuit), 0 is stored in the NOT buffer output loop (turns clockwise between normal and pseudo static NOT)
Now if the input changes to become 1 (the blue) and the gate is closed (a short circuit), what happens to the previous stored light blue zero? I assume it goes into the loop connected to the right after the one in the picture? Does the input 1 charge the capacitor (is it the memory element?) After the capacitor, in the loop output NOT buffer is the 1 stored (turns clockwise between the normal and pseudo static NOT) ?
In addition to understanding how it works, I also lack the overview (or the larger/complete circuit) in which this little one is used ... because by itself as it is, I don't understand its usefulness.
(source: Digital Integrated Circuits: A Design Perspective)
